# Access is denied when use del /f in windows 10 64bit

Tags: windows, cmd, file-permissions

I'm going to delete 1.mp3 but it gives me the error "Access is denied".

More info about file's perms:

```
attrib 1.mp3
A   C:\Users\Alipour\Desktop\1\1.mp3
```

I also used `attrib -s -h 1.mp3`

but still it can not be deleted by

```
del /f/s/q 1.mp3 > NUL
```

or

```
del /f/s/q 1.mp3
```

or

```
del /f 1.mp3
```

Comment: Perhaps the file is accessed by another process?

Comment: @aschipfl: I already mentioned that in my answer, but that doesn't help.

Comment: Files on NTFS partitions also have ACLs (Access Control List) which specify what permissions users and groups have on a file. ACLs are  completely separate from the permissions bits shown by the dir command. To view the ACL permissions right click on the file in Explorer, select "Properties" on the context menu then select the "Security" tab.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several methods to remove such a file:

**1. Process Explorer if the file is in use:**
You can use [ProcessExplorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) from Windows Sysinternals to identifiy which program locks the file. Download and start ProcessExplorer and go to `Find|Find Handle or DLL... Ctrl+F` and enter the name of the locked file: `1.mp3`.

ProcessExplorer will show you the process that is responsible for the lock because of accessing the file. If you've got the proccess kill that one and delete the file.

Example with MS Word accessing a file called *LockedFile.docx*:
[image: ProcessExplorerExample]

---

**2. Safe mode boot:**
Another possibility is to boot into safe mode. In pre Windows 8 era this was done by pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> before Windows boots.
In Windows 8 and higher you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> before Windows boots or more easily you can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click Restart in the login screen or even in Windows. If this was too short, look [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/) how to get into safe mode.

Once you're in the safe mode you can try again deleting that file.

---

**3. Remove file on Windows boot via PendingFileRenameOperations:**
With PendingFileRenameOperations you can rename and even delete a file on Windows boot procedure when nothing else can access and block that file.
PendingFileRenameOperations will be entered in the Windows registry and consists of pairs of file paths.

You can do it manually as described below or again with a Windows Sysinternals program called [MoveFile](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/pendmoves.aspx). Download that program and use it in a console window (Start -> Run or <kbd>Windows-Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `cmd` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>).
Type `movefile foo.exe ""` to delete a file on reboot.

Manual method via registry:
The 1st path is the file to be renamed.
The 2nd path is the new file path.
If the 2nd path is empty (0x0000) the file get's removed.

1. Start -> Run or <kbd>Windows-Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type in `regedit`, and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
3. Goto `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager`
4. Create a new **Multi-String value**: `PendingFileRenameOperations`
5. Enter `\??\filepath` as the data (e.g. `\??\C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\foo.exe`)
6. Press OK
7. Right-click on the key, click **Modify Binary Data**
8. At the end of the hex string, add `0000` (4 zeros which represent an empty string)
9. Press OK
10. Restart your computer

Comment: 0 matching items. @andre-kampling

Comment: @MohammadAlipour: Ok strange, I extended my answer maybe the safe mode will help.

Comment: You might want to use PendingFileRenameOperations which is also able to delete during boot when nothing can block that file. Besides that: is this your desktop or someone else ? What does cacls show for the file ? @MohammadAlipour

Comment: Even easier: once more use a sysinternals utility. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.06.utilityspotlight.aspx

Comment: @Marged: Nice! I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Lean and mean* batch-file only alternatives for **PendingFileRenameOperations**:
~ Scripts will add an entry to right-click -- "SendTo" menu
~ Accepting a single parameter, either File or Folder
~ Confirmation prompt ([Cancel] to Clear previous entries)
~ Basic idiot proofing (don't process %Windir% for example)

[Rename_On_Boot.bat](https://pastebin.com/2Z4R8tBJ)

```js
goto="Batch" /* Rename_On_Boot by AveYo v1
:RenOnBoot
set "input=%*" & call set "input=%%input:?=%%"                            &rem line below adds entry to right-click -- "SendTo" menu
if /i "_%~dp0"=="_%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\" (set .=) else copy /y "%~f0" "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\" >nul 2>nul
if "_%1"=="_" color 4f & echo   ERROR! No input provided & ping -n 6 localhost >nul & exit /b
for %%# in ("C:\" "C:\Boot" "C:\Recovery" "%WINDIR%" "%WINDIR%\system32" "%ProgramData%" "%ProgramFiles%" "%USERPROFILE%") do (
 if /i "_%input%"=="_%%~#" color 4f & echo   ERROR! %%# is not safe to delete & ping -n 6 localhost >nul & exit /b
)
color 0B & echo   Please wait, folders might take a while .. & call cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" RenOnBoot "%input%" & exit /b
:RenOnBoot_Run_As_Admin
color 4f & echo   Asking permission to run as Admin.. & call cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" RunAsAdmin "%~f1???" & exit /b
:"Batch"
@echo off & setlocal disabledelayedexpansion & mode 96,4 & echo. & title %~nx0 by AveYo & if not exist "%~f1" goto :RenOnBoot
reg query HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Environment /v temp 1>nul 2>nul && goto :RenOnBoot || goto :RenOnBoot_Run_As_Admin
:"JScript" */
function RenOnBoot(f){
  var HKLM=0x80000002, k='SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager', v='PendingFileRenameOperations';
  var reg=GetObject('winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//./root/default:StdRegProv'), ws=WSH.CreateObject('WScript.Shell');  
  var confirmation=ws.Popup(" Rename on next boot? [OK]\n Clear previous entries? [Cancel]\n\n "+f,0,'Rename_On_Boot by AveYo',33);
  if (confirmation == 2) { reg.DeleteValue(HKLM, k, v); WSH.quit(); } // Clear existing entries on Cancel press and quit script
  var mtd=reg.Methods_('GetMultiStringValue').InParameters.SpawnInstance_(); mtd.hDefKey=HKLM; mtd.sSubKeyName=k; mtd.sValueName=v;
  var query=reg.ExecMethod_('GetMultiStringValue', mtd), regvalue=(!query.ReturnValue) ? query.SValue.toArray():[,], entries=[];
  var fso=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'), fn=fso.GetAbsolutePathName(f);
  entries.push('\\??\\'+fn,'\\??\\'+fn+'.ren');
  reg.CreateKey(HKLM, k); reg.SetMultiStringValue(HKLM, k, v, entries.concat(regvalue));
}
if (WSH.Arguments.length>=2 && WSH.Arguments(0)=='RenOnBoot') RenOnBoot(WSH.Arguments(1));

function RunAsAdmin(self, arguments) { WSH.CreateObject('Shell.Application').ShellExecute(self, arguments, '', 'runas', 1) }
if (WSH.Arguments.length>=1 && WSH.Arguments(0)=='RunAsAdmin') RunAsAdmin(WSH.ScriptFullName, WSH.Arguments(1));
//
```

[Delete_On_Boot.bat](https://pastebin.com/ZBDCUDBg)

```js
goto="Batch" /* Delete_On_Boot by AveYo v1
:DelOnBoot
set "input=%*" & call set "input=%%input:?=%%"                            &rem line below adds entry to right-click -- "SendTo" menu
if /i "_%~dp0"=="_%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\" (set .=) else copy /y "%~f0" "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\" >nul 2>nul
if "_%1"=="_" color 4f & echo   ERROR! No input provided & ping -n 6 localhost >nul & exit /b
for %%# in ("C:\" "C:\Boot" "C:\Recovery" "%WINDIR%" "%WINDIR%\system32" "%ProgramData%" "%ProgramFiles%" "%USERPROFILE%") do (
 if /i "_%input%"=="_%%~#" color 4f & echo   ERROR! %%# is not safe to delete & ping -n 6 localhost >nul & exit /b
)
color 0B & echo   Please wait, folders might take a while .. & call cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" DelOnBoot "%input%" & exit /b
:DelOnBoot_Run_As_Admin
color 4f & echo   Asking permission to run as Admin.. & call cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" RunAsAdmin "%~f1???" & exit /b
:"Batch"
@echo off & setlocal disabledelayedexpansion & mode 96,4 & echo. & title %~nx0 by AveYo & if not exist "%~f1" goto :DelOnBoot
reg query HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Environment /v temp 1>nul 2>nul && goto :DelOnBoot || goto :DelOnBoot_Run_As_Admin
:"JScript" */
function DelOnBoot(f){
  ListDir=function(src, _root,_list) {
    _root=_root || src, _list=_list || [];
    var root=fso.GetFolder(src), files=new Enumerator(root.Files), dirs=new Enumerator(root.SubFolders);
    while (!files.atEnd()) { _list.push(files.item()); files.moveNext(); }
    while (!dirs.atEnd()) { _list=ListDir(dirs.item().path, _root,_list); _list.push(dirs.item()); dirs.moveNext(); }
    return _list;
  };
  var HKLM=0x80000002, k='SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager', v='PendingFileRenameOperations';
  var reg=GetObject('winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//./root/default:StdRegProv'), ws=WSH.CreateObject('WScript.Shell');  
  var confirmation=ws.Popup(" Delete on next boot? [OK]\n Clear previous entries? [Cancel]\n\n "+f,0,'Delete_On_Boot by AveYo',33);
  if (confirmation == 2) { reg.DeleteValue(HKLM, k, v); WSH.quit(); } // Clear existing entries on Cancel press and quit script
  var mtd=reg.Methods_('GetMultiStringValue').InParameters.SpawnInstance_(); mtd.hDefKey=HKLM; mtd.sSubKeyName=k; mtd.sValueName=v;
  var query=reg.ExecMethod_('GetMultiStringValue', mtd), regvalue=(!query.ReturnValue) ? query.SValue.toArray():[,], entries=[];
  var fso=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'), fn=fso.GetAbsolutePathName(f);
  if (fso.FolderExists(fn)) { var list=ListDir(fn); for (var i in list) entries.push('\\??\\'+list[i],''); }
  entries.push('\\??\\'+fn,'');
  reg.CreateKey(HKLM, k); reg.SetMultiStringValue(HKLM, k, v, entries.concat(regvalue));
}
if (WSH.Arguments.length>=2 && WSH.Arguments(0)=='DelOnBoot') DelOnBoot(WSH.Arguments(1));

function RunAsAdmin(self, arguments) { WSH.CreateObject('Shell.Application').ShellExecute(self, arguments, '', 'runas', 1) }
if (WSH.Arguments.length>=1 && WSH.Arguments(0)=='RunAsAdmin') RunAsAdmin(WSH.ScriptFullName, WSH.Arguments(1));
//
```

Answer (score 1):

When `del /f <FILE>` producing an **Access Denied** error, you need to firstly take owner and grant access using `takeown` and `icacls` command line utilities, Please see an example: [Delete a specific file](https://superuser.com/a/1711475/739463) on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which program is locking a certain file with “*Process Explorer* → Find → Find handles or DLLs.”

For example, if the locker is `explorer.exe`, the *Windows explorer*, you can delete the file after killing *Windows explorer* in *Task manager*.